# Transferring Data Values from Modules to a Program

Tags: variables, fortran

My code is very simple.  The idea of me creating this program is to better understand modules in Fortran.  Could someone please explain how I could get the variable values to my main program.

My module code looks like:

```
module  circlescalculation

double precision:: pi = 3.14159265359
contains

subroutine circumference(radius)
implicit none
double precision :: radius,c
c = 2.0d0 * pi * radius
return
end subroutine circumference

subroutine area(radius)
implicit none
double precision :: radius,a
a = pi * radius**2
return
end subroutine area

end module circlescalculations
```

Now I will be calling this code in my other program:

```
include 'circlescalculations.f90'

program circles

use circlescalculations

implicit none
double precision radius,c,a
print *, "This program calculates the circumference and area of any given 
circle"
print *, "Please specify the radius:"
read *, radius
call circumference(radius)
call area(radius)
print *, "Area" , a
print *, "Circumference" , c
end program circles
```

I am new to Fortran.  I am using the CYGWIN terminal to call to the compiler because I am operating in Windows.  In my terminal I use the following bash:

```
gfortran circlescalculations.f90 -c
gfortran circles.f90 -o test
./test
```

Here is the output which is obviously incorrect.

[image: Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: P.S. the module compiled successfully .

Comment: It seems like you might be new to programming altogether. Is that true? What resources are you using to learn?

Comment: This is quite basic, to some extent, so explaining the full concept is possibly going to count as "too broad".  Hopefully, though, somone can find a good similar question or explain concisely.  Essentially, you'll need to understand about "scope" of variable: the `a` and `c` you are printing have nothing at all to do with the subroutines you are calling, or indeed the module.

Comment: I am just new to FORTRAN.  The C language is not like the Linux counterpart FORTRAN in my opinion.  Thanks I'll go online and download pdf's for scope of variables in FORTRAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `c` and `a` declared in the program `circles` are different than the `c` and `a` defined in the subroutines `circumference` and `area`. Conceptually, you need some way of returning the answers back to the main program, as you say.

There are *many* ways to do this. Depending on the final purpose and personal style, the 'correct' way will vary. I'm just trying to point you in the right direction with this answer.

A good, direct way to return data is to pass a variable where the subroutine will put the answer. You can do:

```
subroutine area(radius,a)
   double precision, intent(IN) :: radius
   double precision, intent(OUT) :: a
   a = pi * radius**2
end subroutine area
```

Now, `radius` and `a` are both arguments to the subroutine area, but one is an *input*, and the other is an *output*. To call this, use:

```
call area(radius,a)
```

Alternatively, you can declare `area` as a function. Good luck!

Comment: So can you tell me exactly what the statement return does?  For some reason I was thinking it would return all my variables calculated in the subroutine into my program.  Does it make them accessible in the module?

Comment: That's a pretty different question. `return` typically ends execution of the current block (function, subroutine). When you put it right before `end subroutine`, it does nothing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802011/is-fortran-return-statement-obsolete/49817413#49817413